# Gerund or Participle?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, participles, present-participles, ing

> While ***waiting*** for service, patrons can enjoy coffee and snacks and mingle with their neighbors in need.

Is "waiting" in this sentence a gerund or participle?

This sentence and question actually came out of an SAT practice test; the answer key says that "waiting" is a gerund and corresponds to the preposition "for". After posting this question and looking at other places too, I am convinced that its a participle describing the noun "patrons". Is that accurate?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The important thing is that it is a verb.

Comment: How can "waiting correspond to for"? While [they are] waiting for service. The "they are" is implied. I do not understand how any self-respecting linguist would deny that.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with johnlee that "waiting" in this sentence should be classified as a participle, not a gerund, if you are working in a framework that makes that distinction.

(Comments by members like BillJ correctly point out that not all frameworks do make this distinction; however, as far as I know, there is not yet a unanimous consensus in favor of the position that it is theoretically impossible to distinguish "gerunds" from "present participles" in English. You can see some relevant comments beneath the following Language Log post : [Gerunds vs. participles](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2639).
The linguist Greg Lee made the following [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359478/gerund-vs-present-participle-i-was-thinking-about-eating-the-apple) on this site about the post:

- > Liberman's post makes no sense to me. Because Liberman as a child couldn't tell the difference between gerund and participle, I'm supposed to assume they're the same? What kind of reasoning is that? – Greg Lee Dec 22 '16 at 5:11
- > I looked below in the comments at Stephen C. Carlson's summarizing the CGEL "argument". He says "OK, I've had a look at CGEL about abolishing the distinction between gerund and participle, and I have to admit that I didn't find the discussion particularly clear or persuasive." Based on his account, I agree with him. – Greg Lee Dec 22 '16 at 5:21

Also, see Araucaria's answer here: [Difference between gerund and present participle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296621/difference-between-gerund-and-present-participle). There is more complicated discussion beneath Greg Lee's answers to "[Do these two sentences use the possessive case of gerunds properly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/258181/77227)" and "[How can you tell when a participle is being used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/327127/77227)")

I disagree with johnlee's statement that "A rule of thumb is that it's a present participle if it's used like a verb, or a gerund like a noun."

The salient characteristic of a participle is not that it is "used like a verb" but that it is a verb used like an *adjective.* (We wouldn't need any special word for a verb used as a verb.)

For example, in the progressive construction ("They are waiting"), the participle "waiting" is used after the copular verb *be,* similarly to how an adjective like "awake" occurs with the copular verb *be* when used predicatively: "They are awake".

To distinguish a participle from a gerund, therefore, you should try to figure out if the verb (or the phrase headed by the verb) is acting more like an adjective--in which case it is a participle--or more like a noun (more properly, according to some linguists, this would say "like a noun phrase")--in which case it is a gerund. (One point that may cause confusion: according to most systems of grammatical terminology for English, neither the term "gerund" nor the term "participle" is applicable if the word actually is a noun or an adjective—only if the word is a verb "acting as"/"used as" as noun or adjective. A noun ending in "-ing" may be categorized as a "gerundial noun" and an adjective ending in "-ing" may be categorized as a "(de)participial adjective", but these are not considered to be the same as gerunds and present participles.)

We can use adjectives after "while":

- > While awake, we generally have a clear sense of a personal “I”-being, which awakens at a specific point early in life.

  (*[According to Matthew: Lecture 8 of 12](https://books.google.com/books?id=F2fRQEox83sC&pg=PT6&dq=%22while+awake,+we%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW5IK02ufaAhVm5oMKHQlhAgg4ChDoAQhWMAk#v=onepage&q=%22while%20awake%2C%20we%22&f=false),* by Rudolf Steiner)

But we can't use nouns referring to states or activities after "while" in a similar fashion:

- *While sleep, people dream.

So it seems to me that "waiting" is not a gerund here, and therefore must be a participle.

(Comments point out that predicative noun phrases can appear after "while", as in "while a student". However, a gerund doesn't have the right meaning to be used in that context.)

Another reason I feel like "waiting" is a participle here is because the sentence seems similar in meaning, and I think in structure, to sentences like "While **patrons are** waiting for service, they can enjoy coffee and snacks and mingle with their neighbors in need." In the preceding sentence, "waiting" is obviously a participle and not a gerund.

Comment: Excellent and correct answer. Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: Whiz-deletion can lead to nominal complements: “While still a kitten, Fluffy had already learned to climb to the top of our apple tree.”

Comment: While I find most classification systems inadequate in some respects when trying to analyse this sort of sentence, essentially dependent on constituency test preference, and would argue that a gradience model is more accurate than rival attempts to lump, I _would_ say that _waiting_ here is nearer the verb end of the cline than the noun (and if a 3-D [tetrahedral] rather than a linear model is preferred, including _adjective_ and _preposition_, it is a long lond way from either of these two extremes). More verby than nouny.

Answer (score 0):

"While (they are) waiting" is what's called a (reduced) participle clause.

- Before going out, ...,
- Instead of complaining about it,...
- In spite of having read....,
- etc.

Following a conjunction or preposition.

So "waiting" would be a participle.

Comment: What is 'Before going out, he dug out his warmest hat' a reduced form of?

Answer (score -3):

It is a present participle.

A rule of thumb is that it's a present participle if it's used like a verb, or a gerund like a noun.

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says:

> gerund
>
> a noun in the form of the present participle of a verb

---

**Edit**:
**This edit has little to do with the OP's question.**
Due to constraints on space and markdown tags in comments, here are some sources for Jason Bassford.

Oxford Collocations Dictionary for Students of English says:

> **waiting**
>   I. **noun**
>   Waiting is used before these nouns: area, list, lounge, period, **room**, staff, time
>
> **swimming**
>   **noun**
>   Swimming is used before these nouns: cap, championship, costume, gala, gear, goggles, instructor, lesson, **pool**, shorts, stroke, suit, thing, trunk
>
> **running**
>   I. **noun**
>    activity/sport
>   • RUNNING + NOUN event, race | gear | clothes (AmE), pants (AmE), **shoe**, shorts, tights (AmE), vest (BrE) | track
>
> **sewing**
>   **noun**
>   • SEWING + NOUN basket, kit | needle, thread | **machine** | room (esp. AmE)

OALD says (in addition to the online version linked to in the comment far below):

> **waiting**
>   wait·ing 7 [waiting] BrE [ˈweɪtɪŋ]  NAmE [ˈweɪtɪŋ]  **noun uncountable**
>   1. the fact of staying where you are or delaying doing sth until sb/sth comes or sth happens
>   • No waiting (= on a sign at the side of the road, telling vehicles that they must not stop there).
>   2. the fact of working as a waiter or waitress

From Roget's II The New Thesaurus 3th Ed.:

> **waiting**
>   **noun**
>   An act or the time of waiting: wait. See CONTINUE.

From [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=waiting):

> **wait·ing**  wātĭng)
>   **n.**
>   1. The act of remaining inactive or stationary.
>   2. A period of time spent waiting.

From [Webster's New World](http://www.yourdictionary.com/waiting#websters?direct_search_result=yes):

> **waiting** wait·ing
>   **noun**
>   Waiting is defined as the process of remaining or staying.

There are tons more, but I suppose these should be more than enough.

Also, please have a look at [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: But that definition is not the only one in use, and in fact many grammarians reject the term 'gerund' as having conflicting definitions. The noun ... verb _ing_-form gradience/grey area has been covered here many times.

Comment: And it would be a gerund if used in the phrase "Patrons were found in the ***waiting*** **room**." Also, it's not being used *like* a verb. It is a verb. In contrast to a gerund, where a verb is being used as a noun.

Comment: @Jason Bassford No, "waiting" in "the waiting room" is an uncountable **noun**,  which is used as a *noun adjunct*, modifying "room".

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Valid point. Hence my wording "rule of thumb".

Comment: @johnlee It's a compound noun, with the gerund being used as an adjective. It's a "room for waiting." (You will never find "waiting" listed in any dictionary as a noun.) It's no different than a "swimming pool," "running shoe," or "sewing machine." And it's definitely not uncountable. Most buildings have only a single waiting room, but the count is still one.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: Well, the guys at [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/waiting?q=waiting), [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/waiting) and Oxford Collocations Dictionary all disagree with you. I'm telling you. It is **neither a gerund nor a verb**. It is a noun listed as a noun in major dictionaries as shown above. The same applies to *swimming*, *running* and *sewing* as well.

Comment: Also, from OALD: `wait·ing 7 [waiting] BrE [ˈweɪtɪŋ]  NAmE [ˈweɪtɪŋ]  noun uncountable` You're confused and mixing "room" and "waiting" up. "*Room*" is of course countable, but "*waiting*" **is** an **uncountable noun**.

Comment: @johnlee Obviously, there is no definitive answer. Different sources define it differently. https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/noun-gerund/ https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/gerund/ (at the botttom) https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/participles-and-gerunds : "We took a skiing vacation. (a vacation for skiing—gerund)." https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/nouncompound.html

Comment: @johnlee Although I see the reference in Oxford to "waiting" as a noun, it's really when it's used *as* a noun, as part of an expression, where that makes sense. It's talking more about function. Merriam-Webster, on the other hand, defines the single word *waiting* only as a verb. (Although it offers noun definitions of the associated *wait*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: 1. You *expressly* said "You will **never**... in **any** dictionary", which has been disproved by **multiple** counterexamples. 2. Merriam-Webster? *No single dictionary has an exhaustive list* of all words or denotations, and you know it very well. 3. OCD *explicitly* lists "waiting" as a **noun** when **used before "room"**, as shown in the above edit made 2 hrs ago if you haven't read it yet. 4.  **function**? That's **exactly** what **parts of speech** are about. "Waiting" *functions as a noun* in "waiting room", or a *noun adjunct* to be more precise.

Comment: @johnlee You're missing the point. There's a big difference between something that *functions as* something else and something that actually *is* something else.  Further, your statement that **waiting room** is "neither a gerund nor a verb" means that you are contradicting the definition of gerund that you yourself provided: "a noun in the form of the present participle of a verb." If you now say that **waiting room** is *not* a gerund, you need to edit your answer to remove that possibility.

Comment: @JasonBassford: 5. Yes, LDCE says it. No, I do **not** contradict the definition. Just because human beings are mammals doesn't mean that all mammals are human beings. **Not all** words ending in "ing" are gerunds in **every** context. 6. I just checked out the sources you presented, and those **bloggers** do appear to disagree with the authors and editors of a number of **dictionaries** I presented (There are more.). I think it is quite obvious which group provides authoritative and credible references.

Comment: @johnlee This sentence and question actually came out of an SAT practice test; The answer key says that "waiting" is a gerund and corresponds to the preposition "for". After posting this question and looking at other places too, I am convinced that its a participle describing the noun "patrons". Do you think that's accurate?

Comment: @johnlee Mignon Fogarty is a very well renowned authority on grammar, and is listed in most grammarians' online references as a being credible. However, I came across something that (to me) gives an actual analysis of the situation rather than just stating a fact.  https://literalminded.wordpress.com/category/morphology/gerunds-and-participles/ According to the linguist, *waiting* in this question is a participle (which we all agree on), and *waiting room* is a gerund. Although, honestly, I would have been happy if it had concluded it wasn't.

Comment: @Jeamz: `a participle describing the noun "patrons".` Yes. it's merely a short form of "While *they are* waiting for service", where the obvious part, "they are" is dropped.

Comment: @JasonBassford: 7. Not all linguists agree on everything (as is the case with her disagreement with CGEL), and *what one linguist asserts is not necessarily a "fact"* until an overwhelming majority of the scholars agree, which agreement is embodied in the form of **dictionaries**. 8. I, too, would've considered it to be a gerund if it were not listed as a noun in dictionaries as you asserted, which, however, is evidently not the case.

Comment: @johnlee: It's certainly true that not all linguistics agree on everything. However, a dictionary is a bad place to look if you want to find out what linguists think.

Comment: (Oops, read "linguists" for "linguistics" in the above comment.) I wrote an answer that describes the parts of this answer that I don't agree with.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "The dictionary definitions ...", which was exactly why I clarified the purpose of the edit. Yes, it does somewhat obfuscate my answer to the OP's question, but I had little options as I stated. Okay, I just added one more line to minimize the potential confusion.